# How can I automatically include a custom configuration file from my class library into my executable project during release?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-services, configuration-files

I have a VS2008 solution which contains a number of class libraries plus an executable project (a windows service). One of my class libraries is a wrapper for a 3rd party component which allows for a great deal of configuration so I created a custom XML document called `3rdPartyConfig.xml` and a strongly-typed parsing class called `3rdPartConfig.cs`.

Since my executable project references that class library, when the app runs it's going to look for the XML file in it's executing location. To do this, I have set the following properties on `3rdPartyConfig.xml`:

- set  `Build Action = Content`.
- set  `Copy to output Directory = Copy always`

When I run in *Debug configuration* I can see `3rdPartyConfig.xml` has been copied to the build output folder . The app runs fine and is able to read the file. However, when I publish as *Release*, Visual Studio *does not* copy the XML file, so when the app runs it cannot find it.

*What can I do to ensure my custom configuration file is included in the Release build output? Do I need to write a pre- or post-build script?*

Caveats:

- I know that a workaround would be to scrap the XML file and add the configuration to the app.config. I have been asked to *not* do it that way (client wants to be able to substitute configuration files easily).
- Another workaround would be to store the configuration info in a database. The client would prefer not to do that either.
- I have adjusted for the fact that "executing location" gets nebulous when dealing with windows services. Rest assured my code *does* check in the installed location, *not* `c:\windows\system32`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just edit the "Copy To Output Directory" property in the solution for your file:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that I tried that as well.

Comment: Setting `Build Action` to `Content` is what solved this problem for me, as shown in the screenshot. Also, I have `Copy to Output Directory` set to `Copy always`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just add the config file as a link to the executable project and set it to copy to the release directory if newer?

Comment: That could work, but can you explain in mere detail how this would be accomplished?